# Android SyncAdapter not firing automatically

Tags: android, android-networking, android-syncadapter

I'm following the SyncAdapter tutorial at https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html. So I've got all of the Stub classes in place, and it's all wired up. The SyncAdapter itself is the one from the tutorial, so does nothing but log a message. The following all work:-

1. The account is visible in settings/accounts
2. Disabling/enabling sync in settings causes a sync
3. Choosing "sync now" causes a sync
4. Calling `mResolver.requestSync(mAccount, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);` causes a sync

However, that's as far as it goes. I'm expecting network events, (eg WiFi becoming available) to trigger a sync, but it isn't.

Have I misunderstood what `mResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount,AUTHORITY,true);` does, or is there something else preventing automatic syncing?

Comment: did you tried to add/delete/modify something in underlaying ContentProvider?

Comment: ...that's why `notifyChange(Uri uri, ContentObserver observer, boolean syncToNetwork)` has it third parameter and thats why we use this method in insert/update/delete implementation of CP ...

Comment: No. The content provider is just a stub. The purpose of my sync is to pull data, not to push it.

Comment: so yes, you misunderstood `setSyncAutomatically` ... use `setSyncAutomatically` with `addPeriodicSync` ... or use GCM to send message to the device that it need to call `requestSync` ... also `requestSync` will not work without `setSyncAutomatically` set to true when you do not force it with SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL

Comment: that makes sense. many thanks. feel free to post an answer for me to accept